# sbt modify the lib output directory when using sbt-native-packager

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

How can I modify the output of the final packaged zip to move the "lib" directory contents up one level. Basically I output a zip and the contents are like so:

```
ZIP FILE CONTENT:
-- my-plugin-1.0.jar
-- /lib
    -- /lib/mydependency1.jar
    -- /lib/mydependency2.jar

 ZIP FILE CONTENT I WISH TO HAVE:
 -- my-plugin-1.0.jar
 -- mydependency1.jar
 -- mydependency2.jar
```

I want to move everything in "lib" up one level to the root output.

sbt version 0.13.0

Here is my build.sbt:

```
import NativePackagerHelper._

organization := "com.company.product"
name := "my-plugin"
version := "1.0"
enablePlugins(UniversalPlugin)
packageName in Universal:= "deployment"
publishArtifact in (Compile, packageDoc) := false
artifactName := {
    (sv: ScalaVersion, module: ModuleID, artifact: Artifact) =>
        artifact.name + "-" + module.revision + "." + artifact.extension
}
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8")
mappings in Universal <+= packageBin in Compile map { jar => jar -> (jar.getName()) }
topLevelDirectory := None
```

plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.0.0")
```

command line:

```
sbt universal:packageBin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your requirement is a first class citizen in `sbt-native-packager`:

```
mappings in Universal ++= contentOf("src/main/resources/cache")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, my question was worded poorly though. I have updated the question to reflect the real problem.

Comment: To solve my "real" problem I had to do this: mappings in Universal ++= contentOf(unmanagedBase.value) so your answer is correct. Now I just have to figure out how to delete the "lib" directory in the zip. Thank you!

Comment: The `mappings` object is just a `Seq[(File, String)]`. Just filter out the strings you don't want with `mappings in Universal := (mappings in Universal).filterNot { case (src, dest) => dest startsWith "lib/"}`